# Java Rotate Image Lost Quality

Tags: java, image-processing, rotation

I have this function for rotating images.Although i am loosing quality.Any there any change which can improve it ?

```
 public BufferedImage RotateImage(String imagePath,int degrees) throws IOException{ 
         File file = new File(imagePath);
         Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
         BufferedImage img=bufferImage(image, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

         AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
         double radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degrees;

         double width = img.getWidth()/2;
         double height = img.getHeight()/2;

         if(degrees != 180){
             tx.translate(height,width);
             tx.rotate(radians);
             tx.translate(-width,-height);
         }else{                      
         tx.rotate(radians,width, height);
         }

         AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
         img = op.filter(img, null);
         return img;
         }
```

Comment: Note that if you had posted an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), **we** could 'try' the other resizing techniques.  For an SSCCE with images, generate one in code or hot-link to an image directly off the net, e.g. one of the images available at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` will always make everything look like blergh. Try using `AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR` or `AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC`.

Comment: Well tried that and image is totally loosing colors . IT changes to some weird green and blue colors .

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with your image’s or buffer’s colorspaces and less like a transformation problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Try using bicubic or bilinear](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/the-myth-of-infinite-detail-bilinear-vs-bicubic.html).  Link shows an example of each.

```
AffineTransformOp op = 
    new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
```

Comment: Well tried that and image is totally loosing colors . IT changes to some weird green and blue colors .

Answer (score 2):

The AffineTransform filtering parameter several others mentioned is important, but it also depends on the encoding your images come in. If it's JPEG, [lossless rotation isn't universally possible](http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/digitalimaging/f/rotatequality.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Try using either
[TYPE_BICUBIC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#TYPE_BICUBIC)

or

[TYPE_BILINEAR](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#TYPE_BILINEAR)